# Makes specific rooms for two logged in users in socket io nodejs

Tags: node.js, django, redis, socket.io

I would like to integrate Socketio django redis and nodejs. My problem is that i dont know how to make a room specific to two logged in users.

Say, For example user A is logged in and user B logs in after 20 minutes, User B should automatically join the room with user A when he clicks on user A's chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save your rooms name on database then, and when user B logged in or click the rooms he/she will be joined with that room name. I prefer using using random generated string for room name.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('join room', (data) => )
    const userA = data.userB;
    const userB = data.userA;
    const roomname = data.roomName;

    // I use mongodb
    const socketRoomName = MyRoomModel.findOne({ roomname })
      .then(response => response)
    socket.join(socketRoomName)
    // send message after user connected to rooms
    socket.to(socketRoomName).emit('online', data.message)
})
```

But if you did not want to use rooms and namespace on socket.io you can handle logged in and mapping them on connection

```
const sessionsMap = {};

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // ask user id on client can be email, must unique
  socket.emit('askForUserId');

  socket.on('userIdReceived', (userId) => {
    // map userid to sessions map
    sessionsMap[userId] = socket.id;
  });

  socket.on('send', (message) => {
    const receiverId = sessionsMap[message.receiverId];
    const messageData = message.data;
    // this will send only on user with that specific user id
    socket.broadcast.to(receiverId).emit('my message', messageData);
  });
});
```

Comment: For the user's id, I am using sessions. Thanks for the answer it really helped.

Comment: Thanks. I suggest you change your question title with related problem based on your question like "Makes specific rooms for two loged in users in socket io nodejs"